# code doesn't work in PyCharm, but work in remote executing

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, remote-server, miniconda, anaconda3

let us see the code firstly:

.py files are organized as follows:

```
A
 - __init__.py
 - B.py
 - C.py

# where A is a python package, C is .py file and there is a D class in C.py file.
```

The B.py file uses D class in C.py file in this way:

```
import A.C

A.C.D()
```

My question comes:

If I open the code in local PyCharm software, there is a clear error saying "No module named 'A' ", and I have to correct the code to `from . import C` and `C.D()`.

HOWEVER,

If I directly executed the code without any correction in the remote environment, It works very well. There is no error about the module A.

Why this happens?

why `import A.C` does not work in PyCharm, but in the remote environment, it works well?

Comment: Check the HOME folder of the PyCharm. When you execute it in PyCharm the imports happen from the files available in the  HOME path if no specific path is provided